# <PrettyPrinter>.pformat(json_data) outputs "unformatted" data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to make a custom formatter decorator to pretty print some json responses.

```
formatter = PrettyPrinter(indent=2, width=50)
def prettify(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        json_data = func(*args, **kwargs)
        if isinstance(json_data, dict) or isinstance(json_data, list):
            return formatter.pformat(json_data)
        return json_data
    return wrapper

class ApiInterpreter(object):
  # ... omitted stuff because not important.
  @prettify
  def get(self, endpoint, data={}):
    return requests.get(self.base_url.format(version=self.version, endpoint=endpoint), data=data, headers=self.headers).json()
```

However, whenever I try to use a method from the command line, it prints out an oddly formatted string.

```
In [1]: api.get('cards')
Out[1]: "{ 'data': [ { '_id': 'snKbGdmHtJGf6gz8y',\n              'inventory': [ 1,\n                         12,\n                         1,\n
```

Why is my pretty formatter outputting oddly when printed? Can I surpress this output and show the pretty output?

Comment: Try `print(api.get('cards'))`, in case it helps.

Comment: Looks like there is some whitespace added in that string. Maybe you just need to `print`, like @Peque said.